# Anchor cluster provider issue

Tags: anchor, web3.js, anchor-program-idl

I have setup the Anchor.toml fiel for the devnet but got the error in the test cases some thing like "request to http://localhost:8899/ failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8899", Why anchor uses localnet, even I set the devnet to Anchor.toml file
This is my anchor.toml file

```
[programs.devnet]
program = "BNhE6E4o3aA44wRoTvbPnrFfmpNrSnuUoWGgLzJ2Mds1"
[registry]
url = "https://anchor.projectserum.com"
[provider]
cluster = "devnet"
wallet = "/home/name/.config/solana/id.json"
[scripts]
test = "yarn run ts-mocha -p ./tsconfig.json -t 1000000 test.ts"
```

I already set to devnet
Also I use anchor.AnchorProvider.env() while initializing in the test script

Comment: Can you please post your `Anchor.toml`?

Comment: Maybe you edited Anchor.toml and forgot to Save ?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you set both programs and provider to devnet.

```
[programs.devnet]
your_program = "Fg6PaFpoGXkYsidMpWTK6W2BeZ7FEfcYkg476zPFsLnS"
```

```
[provider]
cluster = "devnet"
```

You can also set multiple program Ids for different networks, for example:

```
[programs.localnet]
your_program = "Fg6PaFpoGXkYsidMpWTK6W2BeZ7FEfcYkg476zPFsLnS"

[programs.devnet]
your_program = "Fg6PaFpoGXkYsidMpWTK6W2BeZ7FEfcYkg476zPFsLnS"
```

Comment: I already set this but this does not work for me

Answer (score 1):

You likely should change your Solana cli configuration using `Solana config set --url https://api.devnet.solana.com`. If this doesn't solve the issue, confirm that your provider is set to `anchor.AnchorProvider.env()` in your testing code.

Comment: Already set like this

Comment: Delete your target folder and rebuild